# C++ test for divisibility with double

Tags: c++, double, factorial, arithmetic-expressions

why doesn´t `((num / i) % 1 == 0)` work in C++ when num is a double? and how would I instead write this code, that checks for factorials by checking if it leaves a remainder (etc 0.3333).

```
int getFactorials (double num)
{
    int total = 0;      // if (total / 2) is equal too 'num' it is a perfect number.

    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if ((num / i) % 1 == 0)
        {
            cout << i << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: add a cast to integer type before doing the modulo.

Comment: Do you mean [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) or [factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)?

Comment: Factors i guess. I mix them up

Comment: @didierc: if i cast the double (num) to a integer, thus algorithm will not work

Comment: This looks wrong anyway. " doing % 1" returns the remainder when dividing by one. Which will always be zero.

Comment: @J99: not if the number is a double then it will leave 0.4243 something if it does not divide even. That is why this code works only with a floating point value

Comment: But % isn't even defined for floating point values

Comment: @J99 I´ve got that now, I come from Java, i think the modulus operator worked with floating point values over there, or I might have dreamt it in one of my exciting dreams.

Comment: Ah ok, fair enough :) As others have said you probably want fmod then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually what you want to do is check if `n` is divisible by `i` so all you have to change is

```
if ((num / i) % 1 == 0)
```

into

```
if (num % i == 0)
```

You should know that this is error-prone because you are using `double` as a type for `num`. You should use an `int` instead.

Comment: Shouldn't `(num / i) % 1 == 0` work too? (if rounding errors didn't exist)

Comment: if (num % i == 0) would not work. for example if I divide 28 by 4 the answer is 7 not zero, but 4 is an divisor of 28

Comment: @TomLilletveit The `%` operator gives you the **remainder** of the division of `n` by `i`, so if `i` divides `n` it will give you zero.

Comment: Note that casting to `int` doesn't work unless the `double` is really supposed to be close to an integer value. And since floating point numbers don't represent integers exactly once the exponent part is large, they shouldn't be used as such. Use `long long` for large integers.

Answer (score 7):

The `%` operator is only allowed on integral types (and user defined
types which overload it).  For floating point, you need the function
`fmod`.

Answer (score 2):

The `%` operator is defined by C++11 §5.6/4:

> if the quotient a/b is representable in the type of the result, (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a.

This is meaningless for floating point types. The definition of modulus depends on division rounding to an integer.

As James Kanze says, use [`std::fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code return you a double object

```
(num / i)
```

modulo operation is allowed only for int type. You can convert this to int type

```
( ((int) (num / i) ) % i)
```